# Which one is the correct OAuth2 flow

Tags: oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

Tried to implement an OAuth2 in spring. But stuck as to which one would be the correct flow?

One flow I keep `@Order(1) in (WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter)`

Here on hitting the below I am presented with the default login page and I successfully login. `http://localhost:8301/oauth/authorize?client_id=getidfromfacebook&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http://localhost:9191/xyz`
Redirected to the authorize page and after acceptance get a code `http://localhost:9191/xyz?code=mkuyG4` which helps in getting the access and refresh token by `curl http://localhost:8301/oauth/token -H"Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d'grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri=http://localhost:9191/xyz&code=LJQef7' -u getidfromfacebook:getit`
I am also able to get a fresh access token from the given refresh token via `curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:8301/oauth/token?grant_type=refresh_token&client_id=getidfromfacebook&refresh_token=a045acd6-5d66-4db5-a509-4bdadca065e0' -u getidfromfacebook:getit`

The problem I face here is that with the given access token, I am not able to access any of the resources mentioned in 
`antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated() (ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter)`. 
Like in postman provided a Header with `Authorization` and value `Bearer access-token` or like `curl -H"Authorization: Bearer 1738520f-9f9c-43ef-8f7f-f5886075a7aa" http://localhost:8301/api/users/all/`. 
Note, I am able to get access-tokens for other grant_types as well and also refresh it. But no access to resources via the token. Point to note is if I hit the resource url, I am presented with the default login and able to access it.

The other flow I ***remove*** `@Order(1)`. When I try to go through the authorization code flow, the system complains about user needs to be logged in for a request of (auth)code. So not able to proceed as am not presented with the default login page.
However, I am able to proceed with the password grant type `curl http://localhost:8301/oauth/token -d"grant_type=password&username=username&password=userpassword" -H"Content-type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8" -u getidfromfacebook:getit`
I am also able to access the resources via the access token.

Which one is the correct approach? 
Why am I not able to access the resources in former approach.

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
@AllArgsConstructor                            
public class AuthorizationServerConfigAdapter extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
private final ClientService clientService;
private final UserService userService;

@Override
public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) throws Exception {
    security
            .tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()")
            .checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()");
}

@Override
public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
    clients.withClientDetails(clientService);
}

@Override
public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
    endpoints
            .authenticationManager(this.authenticationManager)
            .userDetailsService(userService)
    ;
}

/*****************************/

@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfigAdapter extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
         http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()
            .antMatchers("/").permitAll();
    }
}

/*****************************/

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@AllArgsConstructor
@Order(1) // Since we have this working as N, Z and R sever.
public class WebSecurityConfigAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

private final UserService userService;

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    //http.csrf().disable();

    http
            .antMatcher("/**")
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/oauth/authorize**", "/login**", "/error**")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin().permitAll();
}

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
    authenticationManagerBuilder
            .userDetailsService(userService)
            .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
}

@Bean
@Override
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
    return super.authenticationManagerBean();
}

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(BCryptPasswordEncoder.BCryptVersion.$2A);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .requestMatcher(request -> {
                String auth = request.getHeader("Authorization");
                return (auth != null && auth.startsWith("Bearer"));
            })
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()
            .antMatchers("/").permitAll();
    }
```

Comment: Saw a similar post and got the above there.